# Prevent from applying both styles

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Am building a chrome extension. Where i defined styles for a element `textarea` like this

```
<textarea class='text-area'></textarea>

.text-area {
   padding: 15px;
   border: 2px solid red;
 }
```

But it's looking diffrent on one site to another. Consider a site `www.somesite.com` where they have their own styles for `textarea` like this.

```
textarea {
 background-color: something;
 font: something;
}
```

Browser applying both styles for this `textarea`, But i don't want. This is a simple case, i have similar issue with many other elements in extension. Please suggest me a better way to have my extension unique in all the website where user opens it. Thanks

Comment: Is `.text-area` the whole of your selector? Do yourself a favour and use an id.

Comment: is `id` preferable to use for a reusable components like `text-area`? because i may use `text-area` twice in same form?

Comment: Ah, sorry, from your description I though somehow that your textarea would only appear once on the page.n that case you'd be able to give it a unique ID and never have to worry about other elements which happened to have the same class. My mistake.